# How to insert multiple value in pivot table using attach or sync method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with laravel many to many relationship.In my database seed file I'm add the multiple insert in `pivot_table` using `attach()` method like -

```
 $role_admin->permissions()->attach(array($permission_create,$permission_read,$permission_update,$permission_delete));
```

But when i run the `db:seed artisan command` it's show this error.

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '{"id":1,"name":"Create","slug":"Create","description":"This is basic Create Permission","created_at":"2018-12-17 05:23:31","upda' for column 'permission_id' at row 1")

if i'm use `sync()` instead of `attach()` then show this error.

> ErrorException  : Illegal offset type

Now, I want to know how can i multiple value at a time in my `permisson_role` `pivot Table`

Here,is my `RoleTableSeeder` Sample...

```
class RoleTableSeeder extends Seeder
 {
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $permission_create=Permission::where('slug','Create')->first();
    $permission_read=Permission::where('slug','Read')->first();
    $permission_update=Permission::where('slug','Update')->first();
    $permission_delete=Permission::where('slug','Delete')->first();

    $role_admin=new Role;
    $role_admin->name="Admin";
    $role_admin->slug=ucfirst("admin");
    $role_admin->description="This is Super-Admin Role";
    $role_admin->save();
    $role_admin->permissions()->attach(array($permission_create,$permission_read,$permission_update,$permission_delete));
    //$role_admin->permissions()->sync(array($permission_create,$permission_read,$permission_update,$permission_delete));


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->first()` doesn't return an id, you should use like this: `->first()->id`